# Issue with file-handling

Tags: python, file-handling

I'm coding a small game as the final examination in an introductory course to Python. However, I have run in to an issue with the logging of the player's highscore where the text doesn't append to the txt.-file although the code and the textfile are in the same folder.
This is the function which I do not seem to get to work:

```
def highscore(highscore_file, points, avatar, today):
    logg = open(highscore_fil, 'a')
    logg.write(avatar + '\t\t\t' + str(points) + '\t\t\t' + str(today) + '\n')
    logg.close()
```

highscore_file is the text file 'highscore.txt'

points is just a counter for every move the player makes.

avatar is an input.

today is today's date from the module datetime.

Does anybody know what the issue could be?

Comment: `highscore_fil` Versus `highscore_file`?

Answer (score -1):

`highscore_fil` should be a string and have an extension, so `'highscore_fil.txt'` Unless, of course, this is a variable that points to a txt file. I ran it on my end, and it worked fine after adding the aforementioned changes.

```
def highscore(highscore_file, points, avatar, today):
    logg = open('highscore_fil.txt', 'a')
    logg.write(avatar + '\t\t\t' + str(points) + '\t\t\t' + str(today) + '\n')
    logg.close()
```

Comment: It's a typo. It's suppose to be `highscore_file`, one of the function's parameters.

Comment: *supposed. How ironic.